# Parse Server (express) Error: Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: node.js, express, parse-platform, parse-server

I am using the following function on Parse Server running on [NodeChef](https://www.nodechef.com):

```
var sendMail = function(sendMailData) {
    return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://api.sparkpost.com/api/v1/transmissions',
        body: {
            content: {
                from: 'noreply@domain.com',
                subject: sendMailData.subject,
                template_id: sendMailData.templateId,
            },
            substitution_data: sendMailData.substitution_data,
            recipients: sendMailData.recipients
        },
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'AUTHKEY',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    });
}

sendMail(defaultSendMailData).then(function(okresp) {
    var attemptedSend = false;
    if (request.user.get('config')) {
        var userConfig = request.user.get('config')
        if (userConfig.copyPrescription === true) {
            attemptedSend = true;
            sendMail(defaultSendMailData).then(function(okresp) {
                var attemptedSend = false;
                if (request.user.get('config')) {
                    var userConfig = request.user.get('config')
                    if (userConfig.copyPrescription === true) {
                        attemptedSend = true;
                        sendMail(copyPrescriptionSendMailData).then(function(okresp) {
                            console.log('Woohoo! You just sent your first mailing 1!');
                            response.success("Great! Your program has been sent!");
                        }, function(errresp) {
                            console.log('Whoops! Something went wrong 1');
                            console.log(errresp);
                            response.error(errresp);
                        });
                    }
                };
                console.log('Woohoo! You just sent your first mailing 2!');
                if (!attemptedSend) {
                    response.success("Great! Your program has been sent!");
                }
            }, function(errresp) {
                console.log('Whoops! Something went wrong 2');
                console.log(errresp);
                response.error(errresp);
            });
        });
    }
});
```

and getting the following error:

```
at Immediate.<anonymous> (/bundle/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:618:15) 
at Immediate.<anonymous> (/bundle/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:232:9) 
at next (/bundle/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10) 
at Function.process_params (/bundle/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12) 
at /bundle/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7 
at trim_prefix (/bundle/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13) 
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/bundle/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5) 
at jsonParser (/bundle/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:94:7) 
at next (/bundle/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10) 
at Function.process_params (/bundle/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12) 
at /bundle/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7 
at trim_prefix (/bundle/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13) 
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/bundle/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5) 
at allowCrossDomain (/bundle/index.js:439:9) 
at ServerResponse.header (/bundle/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:719:10) 
at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:344:11) 
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

Whilst the function seems to work, I'm concerned about this error and where it is coming from. I don't believe that this was the case on Parse.com (where i was using this exact same code). This error doesn't show up in my Parse.com logs. Any assistance on making my Parse Server production  deployment actually stick this time (3rd time of trying!) would be great appreciated.

Comment: Why do you declare `attemptedSend` two times?

Comment: Depending on the result of `userConfig` I send a second email with different content to the User.

Comment: Also, your indentation is wrong, and you are missing a lot of closing brackets, and response seems undefined in your example use.

Comment: I see you got some print statements. How is the console output looking?

Comment: [32minfo[39m: Ran cloud function sendUserProgramme with: 
Woohoo! You just sent your first mailing 1!
2016-07-25 10:45:51 Woohoo! You just sent your first mailing 2!
Function seems to run fine... it's after that I get the error
2016-07-25 10:45:52 ERROR

Comment: @Taylorsuk Care to show the layers of code you got for your expressJS? e.g. Code where you define the layers like `express.use(allowCrossDomain)` From stack trace i can see that there is a function call `allowCrossDomain` in bundle/index.js. It is trying to do a call to `resp.setHeader()` and that is giving you grieve. I guess my question is, does function `allowCrossDomain()` belongs to your code?

Comment: I'm using https://www.nodechef.com/docs to run Parse Server so I only have access to the cloud code, which I certainly have not added `allowCrossDomain()` is it as simple as adding that function to the top of my cloud code?

Comment: @Taylorsuk - I have never use `nodechef.com` before so I am unfamiliar. Another question what is this `response` object, pretty sure it is not the same as the NodeJS `response` object right? I have never seen response.success before. Anyway. based on the from stacktrace the problem is around where you have already sent the response out in your `sendMail` function and the lower expressJS layers (gets executed after your code) is trying to set the resp's header again in `allowCrossDomain`. Since it has already been sent out earlier, you can't set it anymore in `allowCrossDomain`.

Comment: @Taylorsuk I suspect your solution could be as easy as just setting the `response` object's statusCode (e.g. if it is NodeJS's response object I'll just do response.statusCode=200) then I'll call the `next()`; method to proceed to the next expressJS layer.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to all comments above in trying to resolve this. I have been contacted by Node Chef who said this:

> The error was been cased by a 2.2.17 parse server update on saturday.
>
> Other users noticed it and reported it and we had to roll back back
>   the updates.
>
> Currently, auto updates have been turned off and you can manually
>   update the server anytime from server settings > runtime settings
>   after you are confident the new version will work well with your app.

The rollback has worked and I don't have any errors now.